# Mysql fulltext search with boolean operators

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to search for values with OR and AND

here is a example for OR

```
SELECT * FROM contacts_items WHERE MATCH (item_id) AGAINST ('(10 | 1)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This works but if I wanted to do AND

```
SELECT * FROM contacts_items WHERE MATCH (item_id) AGAINST ('(10 & 1)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This will attempt to find contacts with 10 and 1 in the same row but I want to search for a contacts who have 10 and 1 as an item_id but over multiple rows

eg

```
contact_id    item_id
    1             1
    1             10
    2             10
```

The AND search would return contact_id - 1

I think this isn't possible with one search but thought I would ask before making the code more complex then it needs be.

Thanks Tim

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are misusing the `AND` and `OR` fulltext search operators. `|` and `&` are [reserved for future use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax); use `+` or `-` as stated in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Another aspect I don't seem to understand from your example is why are you using `fulltext` search if you are using integers. A simple `WHERE item_id IN (1, 10)` would suffice.

However, if you need `fulltext` search I would recommend using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! So is it not possible to find contacts who have item 1 and 10 only ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM contact_items WHERE item_id IN (1, 10);`